# using Selenium RC in python, select_frame not grabbing frame

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to get the frame from the html source below using the following code:

```
idx = self.selenium.get_element_index("GEPNav")
idx = self.selenium.get_element_index("TOCFrames")    
frame = self.selenium.select_frame("TOCFrames")
```

the 2 calls to get_element_index are for testing and they work, but the call to select_frame() returns None.  Not sure why....

```
<html>
<head>
    <TITLE>NYSE Arca Bylaws and Rules</TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/PCX/styles/GEP.css">
    <script language="javascript" src="misc.js"></script>
    <META Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
    <META Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">

    <META Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
</head>

<script language="javascript" src="RenderTOC.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var IntervalID = 0;
IntervalID = window.setInterval('setTimer()', 2000);
</script>

<frameset rows="188, *" border="0" >
    <frame src="/PCXTools/ExchangeNav.asp?SelectedNode=chp_1_1&manual=/PCX/pcxe/pcxe-rules/" name="GEPNav" id="GEPNav" scrolling="no"  FRAMEBORDER="0" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <frame src="/PCXTools/PlatformTOCFrame.asp?SelectedNode=chp_1_1&manual=/PCX/pcxe/pcxe-rules/#chp_1_1" Name="TOCFrames" id="TOCFrames" scrolling="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
</frameset>

<noframes>
      To be viewed properly, this page requires frames.
</noframes>
```